# Regex to group recursive pattern in string and return capture group as array

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a string that looks like this: 
`Hello:A1,A3,A4,AA04`

Right now I have a regex query that looks like this:

```
/(?<g1>[A-Za-z]+):(?<g2>[A-Za-z0-9,]+)/
```

When a match is found I can access it like this:

```
"Hello:A1,A3,A4,AA04".match(/(?<g1>[A-Za-z]+):(?<g2>[A-Za-z0-9,]+)/).groups.g1 // outputs: Hello
```

ok...now I also have `g2`. I need `g2` in an array with the `,` gone. Right now in my code I have done it this way:

```
"Hello:A1,A3,A4,AA04".match(/(?<g1>[A-Za-z]+):(?<g2>[A-Za-z0-9,]+)/).groups.g2.split(',') // outputs: [ 'A1', 'A3', 'A4', 'AA04' ]
```

Now the question is: Is it possible to accomplish this without `.split(',')` by using Regex and have it return like this:

```
"Hello:A1,A3,A4,AA04".match(?).groups.g2 // would output: [ 'A1', 'A3', 'A4', 'AA04' ]
```

I know I'm not the best at explaining this but I tried to find an answer, I'm either missing it or it's not possible. This is not critical or super important just something on my mind. Sorry for the horrible title.

*running Node.js v13.2.0*

Comment: A group can only contain a single string. Use `split`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a ^ to match beginning of string only.  Using lookaheads.
Note that lookaheads doesn't have good browser support.
Also, I don't know/haven't tested the performance characteristics of this versus exec looping.  And to be entirely honest, it's not much cleaner looking than split.  If you want a one-liner, this'll suffice I guess.
I remember for very long strings on other platforms using RegExs like this didn't do well.  But I ended up resorting to other methods to searching anyways.

```js
console.log(
"Hello:A1,A3,A4,AA04".match(/(^[A-Za-z]+(?=:))|((?=,?)([A-Za-z0-9]+))/g)
)
```